# How to deploy a single python script with gitlab-ci?

Tags: python, gitlab-ci

I created a bot in python and wanted to auto deploy it with every new release on my personal gitlab runner.

I have the following .gilab-ci.yml and didn't found a solution for my problem, because the gitlab runner seems to close it every time.

```
image: python:3.7.4

before_script:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - setsid nohup python __main__.py &
  environment:
    name: production
  when: manual
```

I also tried `python __main__.py &`.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab CI isn't really made to be used for hosting applications as you are trying to do.

In the advanced [configurations options](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnerscustom-section) for GitLab CI, there are ways to modify the timeouts, you could try to hijack them but it really isn't what it is meant for.

GitLab CI is meant to execute short term operations to build your code and deploy applications to other servers, not for hosting long running applications.